# Incoming apiserver requests

Tags: kubernetes, devops

is there any option to see what request is reaching apiserver?
I'm struggling with error

```
authentication.go:104] Unable to authenticate the request due to an error: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid
```

Certs are valid. Master node is ready and all operations (kubectl command etc.) works fine.
So I want to know what request cannot be validate. I already added --audit-log-path="" flag to apiserver but the log file was not created.

Comment: Just setting `--audit-log-path=""` is only half the job, one must configure an [audit policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/audit/#audit-policy) to tell it _what_ to log

Comment: is it possible to edit kube-apiserver command in latest k8s versions? I tried editing manifest/kube-apiserver.yaml but container doesn't start.

Comment: "but container doesn't start ..." and instead does what? You will need to use `docker logs` or `ctr logs` to see what it complained about before kubelet tried to restart it